# Width of flex-container doesn't expand when flex item contains a variable width image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The problem arises when there is a variable width image set to `max-height: 100%;` in a flex-item.  When the page loads flex box successfully gets the width for the current size of the flex-item, however if you resize the browser which forces the image to decrease in size (or increase), the outer container does not follow the new width.

If you run the code snippet below in full screen you'll see on initial load the image is fully surrounded by the pink box, but when you resize (make the height smaller) the image shrinks and the flex container stays at the same width.

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: deeppink;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  border: 10px solid deeppink;
}

.flex-left {
  width: 250px;
}

.flex-right img {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-left">
    <h2>Testing headline</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus quia nemo qui ipsam? Temporibus sint necessitatibus expedita, eum quae tempora voluptas dolore facere voluptate! Possimus molestias non commodi. Officiis, iste?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-right">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/1000/650" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a percentage height to the image container.

The image is already flexible, because its dimensions are set in percentages. With a percentage height on the container, it becomes flexible, as well.

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lofru93/2/)

```css
.flex {
  display: inline-flex;
  background-color: deeppink;
  height: calc(100vh - 20px);
  border: 10px solid deeppink;
}

.flex-left {
  width: 250px;
}

.flex-right {
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-left">
    <h2>Testing headline</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Necessitatibus quia nemo qui ipsam? Temporibus sint necessitatibus expedita, eum quae tempora voluptas dolore facere voluptate! Possimus molestias non commodi. Officiis, iste?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-right">
    <img src="http://unsplash.it/1000/650" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This still doesn't work: https://www.dropbox.com/s/odxur3kfg8tuy01/Screenshot%202017-10-16%2016.58.31.png  The pink area should shrink to match the image.

Comment: I tested it on Chrome and Firefox and it works fine. Pink area shrinks with image. What browser are you using?

Comment: It shrinks when resizing from right to left.  Try resizing from top to bottom.  That's when it breaks for me.

Comment: I'm talking about vertical re-sizing. I tested both vertical and horizontal. It works for me exactly as you want in Chrome and FF. Haven't tested other browser. Did you test the fiddle demo I posted?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/10p6mmdpk0dwynf/flexbox-test.mov , that's your fiddle.  Also, I tested this in chrome and safari no luck.

Comment: What OS?  @Michael_B

Comment: Ok looks like it does function in Chrome and Firefox, but not safari.